# What's the rule to differentiate elements of Schur modules?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, littlewood-richardson-coefficients

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Fulton in "Young Tableaux, with Applications to Representation Theory and Geometry" defines the Schur module $S_{\mu} V$ (for a partition $\mu$) to be the tensor product $V^{\otimes |\mu|}$ modulo the antisymmetrizing relations, and some other relations, called exchange relations.

In the case of polynomials ($\mu = (d)$), there is a good way to think about the modules $S_{\mu} V$ and $(S_{\mu} V)^*$, that is $S_{\mu} V$ is the $d$-th graded piece of the symmetric algebra $\operatorname{Sym} ^{\bullet} V$, and $(S_{\mu} V)^*$ is the submodule of $(V^*)^{d}$ consisting of tensors invariant with respect to the action of the symmetric group (the symmetric tensors $S^d (V^*)$). This way of thinking works also in positive characteristic and enables us to define differentiation
$$
\operatorname{Sym}^e V \otimes S^d (V^*) \to S^{d-e} (V^*).
$$

What is a good way to think about the module $(S_{\mu} V)^*$? How to define for any two partitions $\lambda, \mu$, a differentiation map
$$
S_{\lambda} V \otimes (S_{\mu} V)^* \to \bigoplus_{\nu} (S_{\nu} V)^*?
$$
What is a combinatorial description of this map? J. Towber in "Two new functors from modules to algebras" defines in Section 1.3 the divided power algebra, whose graded pieces are $(S_{\mu} V)^*$, and in Section 2.3 describes the pairing for $\lambda = \mu$, but it is in old language, and hard for me to understand.

Comment: By $(S_\mu V)^*$ do you just mean the dual vector space to $S_\mu V$? If so why is that not a satisfying definition, do you expect a simpler description of this vector space?

Comment: @AntoineLabelle, you are right, I will rephrase the question.

Comment: It feels like you want a version of the Littlewood–Richardson rule proved by explicit module homomorphisms. This is possible for the special cases of the Young and Pieri rules (I think Young's rule should be the same as your differentiation above), and known to be tricky in general. One try is Zelevinsky's pictures: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~billey/classes/Hopf.algebra/bulletins/zelevinsky.1981.pdf. Also (see reference [1]) there is an earlier related paper by James and Peel.

Comment: Is there a distinction between the functors $\mathrm{Sym}^e$ and $S^d$ ? If not, it might be clearer to use the same notation throughout in your first displayed equation.